# Force cropper to always be either full width or full height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cropper

I have been using cropper js.

I am resizing the cropper based on input values(integer). For example A and B.

So when user enters A = 200 and B = 240. The cropper calculates the aspect ratio and shows the cropper. Is there a option or some kind of hack to force the cropper to either force it to fill the width or height based on the ratio?

If i was unclear in my question see images below.
First there is an incorrect image where i got spaces on both sides and at the top and bottom.
[Incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8AGo.jpg)

This image is correct:
[Correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ykRp.jpg)
So at the correct image the user shouldn't be able to make it smaller, and if the the ratio get's below 1 in ratio it should fill the height instead of width.

Do someone have a good soultion on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! 
If someone looking for the answer, what i did -->
Set following options to cropper:

- viewMode: 2 (not necessarily 2, but needs to be more than 0).
- cropBoxMovable: true. (Could only change the cropBox by my inputs.)
- dragMode: 'none'. Otherwise the user could drag a new cropBox.
- cropBoxResizable: false. OtherWise user could drag in the corners in of crfopbox and change size.